# Handling records with shared substructure in Elm

Tags: polymorphism, algebraic-data-types, elm

I have some record types structured essentially like this:

```
type Body x = { x | pos: (Int,Int) }
type Bubble = Body { radius: Int }
type Box = Body { width: Int, height: Int }
```

Now I would like to have a mixed list of any of these and perform some operation on the `Body` part, but still special case handling `Box` and `Bubble` other times. For example, having (implementations elided):

```
mv: (Int,Int) -> Body a -> Body a
bubble: Bubble
box: Box
```

I would like to

```
map (mv (1,1)) [box,bubble]
```

but this fails because Elm deems the types in the list incompatible.

Now I could wrap the `Box`es and `Bubble`s in an ADT like so:

```
type BodyWrap = BoxWrap Box | BubbleWrap Bubble
```

but then I need to do an unwrapping and rewrapping in every case. If I want to fold on the mixed list it gets even messier. An example is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jastice/2226ddab0226561cefc5).

Is there a more elegant way of handling this situation?

Comment: You cannot have heterogeneous list in Elm. This means that all of the types in a list must be the same. Your wrapper solution will work but is messy. Another approach is to create a data type that holds the functions you would like to have in common (similar to OO). Here is an article related to doing this: https://github.com/Dobiasd/articles/blob/master/from_oop_to_fp_-_inheritance_and_the_expression_problem.md#elm-version

Comment: I guess I've run into something that's easy in Scala and hard in Elm then. But thanks, that's a start!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem goes away when using composition rather than inheritance.

Instead of wrapping the whole structure in an ADT, make one field in the record hold an ADT with the object-specific properties:

```
type Body = { pos: (Int,Int), shape: Shape }
data shape = Bubble Int | Box (Int,Int)
```

This allows using the shared structure in `Body` while matching on `shape` only when necessary.

Comment: you know that feeling when a knot untangles itself through sheer force of will? Exactly, you only get that in programming...